# How to compare the values of two columns and reorder the values based on comparison

Tags: python, dataframe

I am new to python and I faced a hard problem that I could not figure out how to do it. I need to compare values in two columns and then reorder the values based on this comparison. For example, let's assume we have the following dataframe. Now I need to check the values in B if they are smaller than the values in the cumulative sum of A. If a value in B higher than the value in cum of A then we stop at that row. And we reorder the observation based on the numerical value of column B until that row (the row is also included).

For instance, when we look at the values in B we see that all the values are smaller than the values in A until part 4.

| Part No | A | B | cum of A |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 13 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 | 17 | 6 |
| 3 | 7 | 15 | 13 |
| 4 | 5 | 16 | 18 |
| 5 | 10 | 19 | 28 |
| 6 | 9 | 16 | 37 |
| 7 | 8 | 12 | 45 |

So that I need to reorder all values based on numerical values in B until part 4 (part 4 is also included). Then the new table should be

| Part No | A | B | cum of A |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 13 | 2 |
| 3 | 7 | 15 | 9 |
| 4 | 5 | 16 | 14 |
| 2 | 4 | 17 | 18 |
| 5 | 10 | 19 | 28 |
| 6 | 9 | 16 | 37 |
| 7 | 8 | 12 | 45 |

And if there is still a higher value in cum of A than the values in B among these reordered observations (first four parts), then part 4 will be taken out from the list and put in a separate list.

This process should be repeated until all parts will be ordered.

Could anyone help me to get the code for this part?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [ { "Part No": 1, "A": 2, "B": 13, "cum of A": 2 }, { "Part No": 2, "A": 4, "B": 17, "cum of A": 6 }, { "Part No": 3, "A": 7, "B": 15, "cum of A": 13 }, { "Part No": 4, "A": 5, "B": 16, "cum of A": 18 }, { "Part No": 5, "A": 10, "B": 19, "cum of A": 28 }, { "Part No": 6, "A": 9, "B": 16, "cum of A": 37 }, { "Part No": 7, "A": 8, "B": 12, "cum of A": 45 } ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
smaller_indexes = len(df[df['B'] > df['cum of A']]) + 1 # check where B is larger than 'cum of A', take the length of that part of the dataframe and add 1 to get the index number of the last value to use for sorting
df[:smaller_indexes] = df[:smaller_indexes].sort_values(by=['B']) # slice the dataframe by the found index number, and sort only that slice of the dataframe
df['cum of A'] = df['A'].cumsum() #recount the cumsum of the entire dataframe
```

This will output:

|  | Part No | A | B | cum of A |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 13 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 | 7 | 15 | 9 |
| 2 | 4 | 5 | 16 | 14 |
| 3 | 2 | 4 | 17 | 18 |
| 4 | 5 | 10 | 19 | 28 |
| 5 | 6 | 9 | 16 | 37 |
| 6 | 7 | 8 | 12 | 45 |

Answer (score 1):

I know it is a little rough but if you want, you can use below:

```
#order the values in list
def order(a):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        # print(i)
        b = a[i-1] - a[i]
        
        if b>0:
            temp = a[i-1]
            a[i-1] = a[i]
            a[i] = temp
            for j in range(i,0,-1):
                b = a[j-1] - a[j]
                if b>0:
                    temp = a[j-1]
                    a[j-1] = a[j]
                    a[j] = temp
    return a

b = [13,15,16,17,19,16,12]

a = [2, 7, 5, 4, 10, 9, 8]

#other list to append the last value if cum is greater than value of "b" after ordering b
otherList = [] 

# isRecursive and indexToTake is for: 
# "And if there is still a higher value in cum of A than the values in B 
# among these reordered observations (first four parts), then part 4 will be 
# taken out from the list and put in a separate list."

def solve(isRecursive, indexToTake):
    c = 0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        c += a[i] #cum sum
        if c> b[i]: #check if cum is greater than the value of "b" at that index
            if isRecursive:
                if i >indexToTake:
                    return
                otherList.append(b[indexToTake])
                return
            b[0:i+1] = order(b[0:i+1])
            solve(True, i) #check if the values at "b" are greater than cum after ordered until the indexToTake
            break

solve(False, 0) #start solving
```